# Vietnam visa for UK citizen

Tags: visas, uk, vietnam, repeat-visits

I am visiting Vietnam in November 2015, I will entering the country on the 10th and my flight home is 14 days later, I will be leaving Vietnam and travelling to Cambodia in between the 2 weeks then travel back into Vietnam to get my flight home on the 24th November, do I need a visa? Can't get hold of anyone at Embassy and not clear about entering twice on the website.

Answer (score 5):

For the first leg of your journey, you're good to go because for visits of 15 days or less, the 'visitor' rule is engaged...

> As of 1 July 2015, British passport holders travelling for tourism or
>   business will be able to enter Vietnam for up to 15 days without a
>   visa. If you’re travelling for business reasons you should contact the
>   relevant Vietnam government department before travel to check whether
>   any licenses are required to carry out your duties.

For your return journey to Vietnam, a different rule is engaged...

> You’ll still need a visa to enter Vietnam for periods of 15 days and
>   longer and if you wish to re-enter Vietnam within 30 days of your
>   departure.

Because you are returning to Vietnam after two weeks, you will not have cleared the 30 day cooling off period.  You will have to get a visa or stay in Cambodia for at least 30 days.

The standard advice for your predicament is...

> The safest option is to get a visa from the Vietnamese Embassy before
>   you travel. If you plan to leave Vietnam and re-enter from another
>   country make sure you get a multiple visit visa.

All citations in this answer come from [Vietnam: Entry Requirements](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/vietnam/entry-requirements) (The Foreign Office)

Comment: If the Visa is for the second entry to vietnam, then getting one in advance is the *only* option, as the pre-approved visa on arrival is only available for arrivals and HCMC, Hanoi and Da Nang airports. (And incidentally, it would not be possible to get a visa for only the first entry and do the second entry visa free. According to the Vietnamese embassy "If you enter Viet Nam the first time with visa, then the next entry without visa can be less than 30 days after your previous exit"

Comment: I did this some years ago with a visa from Vietnam. They were perfectly happy to issue a multiple-entry visa for this purpose after providing my itinerary.

Answer (score 0):

Updates on June 18th, 2015: Nationals of certain countries may visit Vietnam without visa for a period of time.
Starting from July 1st, 2015 to June 30, 2016 visitors from the following countries may not need a visa to Vietnam for less than 15 days: Germany, France, United Kingdom, Italy, and Spain.
First time you don't need a visa.
Second time if you want to come back Vietnam which don't need visa you have to wait after 2 weeks.

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references for this?